# truffle migrate does not return anything

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

I am following the [tutorial from Truffle](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop) to create a "pet shop" contract. I can follow everything until he tells me to `truffle migrate`.

Here is the contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Adoption{
    address[16] public adopters;

    function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
    require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);

    adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

    return petId;
}

function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
    return adopters;
}
}
```

The migrate #1:

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

The migrate #2:

```
var Adoption = artifacts.require("./Adoption.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Adoption);
};
```

[image: truffle migrate does not do anything]

The network seems to be configured right on the truffle-config file

```
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // for more about customizing your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

And Ganache(testing) seems to not have mined any blocks even though the network is right:
[image]

It is weird, I haven't found anyone else with the same issue as me, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to do `sudo truffle compile`
After using sudo to compile `truffle migrate` worked as it was supposed to.

Comment: I'd suggest to fix the permissions in your project files so you can run truffle without sudo.